# bash script dictionary lookup

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I have a random integer lookup returning 6 integers. From these 6 integers I need to find each string associated with that integer in my dictionary.txt file, and then concatenate each of the found words.

dictionary:

```
...
65161   yokel
65162   yolk
65163   yon
65164   yond
65165   yore
65166   york
65211   yost
65212   you
65213   you'd
65214   young
65215   your
65216   youth
...
```

So far I have

```
curl "http://www.random.org/integers/?num=6&min=11111&max=66631&col=1&base=10&format=plain"
29215
60374
46137
57290
35214
32278
```

So I just need to take these 6 numbers and concatenate each found associated word. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
words=$( grep -Fwf <( curl ... ) dictionary | grep -oP '(?<=\s)\S+' )
```

or

```
words=$( awk 'NR==FNR {num[$1]; next} $1 in num {print $2}' <( curl ... ) dictionary )
```

then

```
echo $words   # no quotes
```

Comment: would this only return one word? I need to concatenate all 5 returned words.

Comment: all six words. try it.

Answer (score 0):

If your `dictionary.txt` file is one word per line, and if you pull the number `123`, you want the word on the 123rd line of the file, you can do this:

```
NUM=$(curl "http://www.random.org/integers/?num=6&min=11111&max=66631&col=1&base=10&format=plain")
WORD=$( sed -n "${NUM}p" dictionary.txt
echo "$NUM $WORD"
```

If your `dictionary.txt` file contains both the number and the word on each line, you can do this:

```
NUM=$(curl "http://www.random.org/integers/?num=6&min=11111&max=66631&col=1&base=10&format=plain")
WORDLINE=$( sed -n "/${NUM}/p" dictionary.txt
echo "$WORDLINE"
```

Comment: I just need to take the 6 return values from curl, and match it to the dictionary word which is located one space over from the number. And then concatenate the 6 returned words from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl "..." | grep ^"$a" dictionary.txt | awk '{printf $2}'; done
```